# How to Implement Simpler Microphone Permission Dialog Box in Flash

Tags: flash, permissions, webcam, microphone

Instead of this dialog box for microphone access:

[image]

I want to use this one:

[image]

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could force the permission dialog by setting the microphone loopback on.

```
var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
mic.setLoopBack(true); // Force permission dialog
mic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, function (e:StatusEvent):void {
    mic.setLoopBack(false);

    switch (e.code) {
        case "Microphone.Muted":
            trace("Microphone permission denied");
            break;
        case "Microphone.Unmuted":
            trace("Microphone permission accepted");
            break;
    }
}
```